# Cambiar varios Select a traves de solo uno con jquery

Tags: jquery, combobox, array

bueno como dice el titulo necesito cambiar varios `select` cuando selecciono uno que lo tengo como encabezado de los otros, pondré mi ejemplo en código:

```
//Este es el select que tiene que cambia a los otros al yo seleccionar alguna de sus opciones
<select name="select_encabezado">
    <option value="1">uno</option>
    <option value="2">dos</option>
    <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>

<br><br>

//Select que deben ser afectados
<select name="otros_select[]">
    <option value="1">uno</option>
    <option value="2">dos</option>
    <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>
<select name="otros_select[]">
    <option value="1">uno</option>
    <option value="2">dos</option>
    <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>
<select name="otros_select[]">
    <option value="1">uno</option>
    <option value="2">dos</option>
    <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>
...
...
```

O sea que cuando cambie el `select` encabezado, por ejemplo a la opción "dos", los otros deben cambiar a la misma opción.

Comment: Editado, gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De esta forma:

```js
$('.select_encabezado').on('change', function() {
  $('.otros_select').val(this.value);
  // forma más larga
  //$('.otros_select').val(this.value).prop('selected', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//Este es el select que tiene que cambia a los otros al yo seleccionar alguna de sus opciones
<br>
<select name="select_encabezado" class="select_encabezado">
  <option value="1">uno</option>
  <option value="2">dos</option>
  <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>

<br>
<br> //Select que deben ser afectados
<br>
<select name="otros_select[]" class="otros_select">
  <option value="1">uno</option>
  <option value="2">dos</option>
  <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>
<select name="otros_select[]" class="otros_select">
  <option value="1">uno</option>
  <option value="2">dos</option>
  <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>
<select name="otros_select[]" class="otros_select">
  <option value="1">uno</option>
  <option value="2">dos</option>
  <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>
```

El truco esta en la clase `otros_select`, cada vez que cambia el *select* principal, cambiamos los otros *select* en el evento `on`.

Comment: ¿No crees que el `prop('selected', true)` es redundante?

Comment: @PaulVargas tienes razón, lo edité.

Comment: si usaras la misma `class` en los `select` que se cambian evitarías poner lineas de mas

Comment: @JuankGlezz cierto.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me sirvio!

Comment: Excelente... :)

Answer (score 2):

Usando `jQuery` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
$('select[name="select_encabezado"]').on('change', function() {
  $('select[name*=otros_select]').val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select_encabezado">
    <option value="1">uno</option>
    <option value="2">dos</option>
    <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<select name="otros_select[]">
    <option value="1">uno</option>
    <option value="2">dos</option>
    <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>
<select name="otros_select[]">
    <option value="1">uno</option>
    <option value="2">dos</option>
    <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>
<select name="otros_select[]">
    <option value="1">uno</option>
    <option value="2">dos</option>
    <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>
```

Update: Gracias a @PaulVargas por su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42721/cambiar-varios-select-a-traves-de-solo-uno-con-jquery/42727?noredirect=1#comment73714_42727)

Explicación:

- No suscribimos al evento `change` del primer `select` (eg: `select_encabezado`)
- Luego, cada vez que es detectado dicho evento, buscamos los otros `select` usando el [selector de atributo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo) de `CSS`.
- Y por cada uno de estos seteamos el valor igual al del primero.

Comment: ¿No bastaría con usar simplemente `$( selector-for-selects ).val(this.value);`, i.e. sin usar `each`?

Comment: @PaulVargas, así es, gracias!

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me sirvio!